# How to do basic authentication with empty password using spring security?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security, basic-authentication

I'm using spring security (2.0.6) to perform HTTP BASIC authentication. I've written a custom authentication provider class which I use to validate usernames and passwords against my database. The problem I'm having is that some users do not have passwords. These users receive an "Access Denied" message. I debugged the code and found that my custom authentication provider isn't invoked when the user's password is blank. Does anyone know how to get around this? I need to allow some users to have blank passwords.

Comment: so if someone doesn't have a password your security is defeated, if you rectify this.

Comment: It's a business requirement that I have to impelement. Yes it may sound insane but there are some business cases where you sometimes need some accounts to be able to login without a password.

Comment: How do you submit a request with blank password, e.g. curl -u user: url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather then no password have you tried setting the password in a filter before the AuthenticationProvider to some default like "NOPASSWORD"?  I think one of the pre-auth filters does a simple 'if (password == null)' and fails and that's your issue.